# numpy - how to add a value to every element in the first column of an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
array([('6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001), ...,
       ('45164194', 1.0413482803123399e-24, 0.99999999997453404),
       ('45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.99999999997635303),
       ('45164519', 3.7521365799080699e-24, 0.99999999997453404)], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
```

And I want to turn it into this: (adding a prefix '2R' onto each value in the first column)

```
array([('2R:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2R:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2R:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001), ...,
       ('2R:45164194', 1.0413482803123399e-24, 0.99999999997453404),
       ('2R:45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.99999999997635303),
       ('2R:45164519', 3.7521365799080699e-24, 0.99999999997453404)], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
```

I looked up some stuff about nditer (but I want to support earlier versions of numpy.)  Also I'm reading one should avoid iteration.

Comment: I was thinking I could reference just the first column and apply a function on that, but I'm getting `index error: invalid index` when I try this: `array[:,0]`

Comment: With a `np.rec.array` you would be able to access those columns using `array["pos"]`. But I don't know how to add anything in the "string addition broadcasting" manner you are looking for.

Comment: hmm, I can access the first column with array['pos'] but I'm not sure how to modify the values from there.  (assuming that's the right direction)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element-wise string concatenation in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958506/element-wise-string-concatenation-in-numpy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`numpy.core.defchararray.add`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.add.html):

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> from numpy.core.defchararray import add
>>>
>>> xs = array([('6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
...             ('6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
...             ('21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),
...             ('45164194', 1.0413482803123399e-24, 0.99999999997453404),
...             ('45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.99999999997635303),
...             ('45164519', 3.7521365799080699e-24, 0.99999999997453404)],
...            dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
>>> xs['pos'] = add('2R:', xs['pos'])
>>> xs
array([('2R:6506', 4.67259718014735e-25, 0.999999999950887),
       ('2R:6601', 2.24527453887999e-27, 0.999999999952706),
       ('2R:21801', 1.98496509218366e-31, 0.99999999997999),
       ('2R:45164194', 1.04134828031234e-24, 0.999999999974534),
       ('2R:45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.999999999976353),
       ('2R:45164519', 3.75213657990807e-24, 0.999999999974534)],
      dtype=[('pos', 'S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
```

UPDATE: You can use [`num.char.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.add.html) instead of `numpy.core.defchararray.add` (commented by @joel-buursma):

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.char == numpy.core.defchararray
True
```

Comment: Impressive solution. If we were to append (instead of prepend) `'2R:'`, would this function handle its task significantly differently according to whether 'S100' leaves enough space or not? (Imagine for example that the number has 98 digits.)

Comment: @eickenberg, According to an experiment (http://pastebin.com/dVRyJmQH), `add` (both prepend/append) truncate trailing parts according to the size specified.

Comment: You can now use `np.char` instead of `numpy.core.defchararray`. (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.add.html)

Comment: @JoelBuursma, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

A simple (albeit perhaps not optimal) solution is just:

```
a = np.array([('6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),
       ('45164194', 1.0413482803123399e-24, 0.99999999997453404),
       ('45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.99999999997635303),
       ('45164519', 3.7521365799080699e-24, 0.99999999997453404)],
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])


a['pos'] = [''.join(('2R:',x)) for x in a['pos']]

In [11]: a
Out[11]:
array([('2R:6506', 4.67259718014735e-25, 0.999999999950887),
       ('2R:6601', 2.24527453887999e-27, 0.999999999952706),
       ('2R:21801', 1.98496509218366e-31, 0.99999999997999),
       ('2R:45164194', 1.04134828031234e-24, 0.999999999974534),
       ('2R:45164198', 1.09470356446595e-24, 0.999999999976353),
       ('2R:45164519', 3.75213657990807e-24, 0.999999999974534)],
      dtype=[('pos', 'S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
```

While I like @falsetru's answer for using core numpy routines, surprisingly, list comprehension seems a bit faster:

```
In [19]: a = np.empty(20000, dtype=[('pos', 'S100'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])

In [20]: %timeit a['pos'] = [''.join(('2R:',x)) for x in a['pos']]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit a['pos'] = add('2R:', a['pos'])
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop
```

Definitely benchmark your own use case and hardware to see which makes more sense for your actual application though. One of the things I've learned is that in certain situations, basic python constructs can outperform numpy built-ins, depending on the task at hand.

Comment: Interesting results in timing it.  Thanks!

Comment: both the solutions throw errors for me: `join` : `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, numpy.bytes_ found` and `add`: `TypeError: must be str, not numpy.bytes_`

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly faster solution is to use list comprehension with `+` operator. Though I do not understand why it is faster. But it is definitely very elegant and basic.

```
a['pos'] = ["2R:" + x for x in a['pos']]
```

Timings:

```
%timeit a['pos'] = ["2R:" + x for x in a['pos']]
8.07 ms ± 64.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit a['pos'] = [''.join(('2R:',x)) for x in a['pos']]
9.53 ms ± 391 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit a['pos'] = add('2R:', a['pos'])
14.2 ms ± 337 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

PS: I created the array `a` using slightly different definition:

```
a = np.empty(20000, dtype=[('pos', 'U5'), ('par1', '<f8'), ('par2', '<f8')])
```

as if I use type `Sxxx` for `pos`, concatenation produces a type error for me.

Comment: Note that you end up with a list in this case, you need to convert `a` to a numpy array again if needed: `a = np.asarray(a)`.