# How to combine strings from 2 numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

arr = [12345, 12345, 12345, 12345]
paths = [67890, 67890, 67890, 67890]

How can I combine these two numpy arrays to get this output below?
output = [1234567890, 1234567890, 1234567890, 1234567890]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element-wise string concatenation in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958506/element-wise-string-concatenation-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
arr_list = [arr, paths]
result = np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 0, arr_list)
```

Comment: I suspect a list comprehension with zip will be faster.

Comment: I also thought of it. But, I've not compared performance @hpaulj

Comment: `numpy.char.add(arr,path)` could be another option, maybe it is easier to read.